# Which direction among the two should we choose for area vector of a plane?

Tags: vectors, area, convention

How can we determine the direction of area vector of a plane among the two perpendicular directions to the plane?

I have read in [this website](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node4.html) that its direction is conventionally determined by right hand grip rule. But how can we apply right hand grip rule to a simple plane?

Comment: Making this choice is equivalent to orienting the surface, i.e., determining the direction used to "walk" around its boundary, or determining which side is "inside" and which "outside". At some point, you have to choose / make up a convention

Comment: Well, then if you choose a convention, then throughout the problem you should use the same convention. However I have no idea how to apply right hand grip rule to choose a convention. Can you please explain with an example.

Answer (score 0):

The convenction usually used is the same as for the cross product of two vectors, i.e. the right-hundle orientation.

[image]

Comment: Here we have two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ from which we can apply the right hand rule. However a given plane has no vectors. Then how can we apply right hand rule?

Comment: If we have no vectors, we cannot orient an area.  In a  plane, interpreted as a two dimensional vector space, we can always take a basis so we have two oriented vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$. Obviously he choice of a base is always arbitrary.

Comment: Suppose we have two or more separate area vectors in a mathematics problem. Then we should apply the same convention to all the area vectors. How shall we apply the same convention to all? Can you please explain this in the answer with an example?

Comment: If we arbitrarily choose the basis in each of the area vectors, then all of them obviously will not be following the same convention.